# How can I embed messages using a Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I want to code a bot that will embed a user's sent message in a specific channel. If you know anything about GTA RP servers, it's like a Twitter or Instagram bot.

Here's an example:

[image: screenshot of example embeds]

I think it's something about the `console.log` and the author's name, but I'm not sure so that's why I'm here. How can I embed users' messages like
this?

Comment: You can create a `MessageEmbed`. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), like programmerRaj said, or use the `embed` property in [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions):

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('some title')
  .setDescription('some description')
  .setImage('image url')

// Discord.js v13
// These two are the same thing
channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
channel.send({
  embeds: [{
    title: 'some title',
    description: 'some description',
    image: {url: 'image url'}
  }]
})

// Discord.js v12
// These two are the same thing
channel.send(embed)
channel.send({
  embed: {
    title: 'some title',
    description: 'some description',
    image: {url: 'image url'}
  }
})
```

To send an embed of users' message in a particular channel, you can do something like this, where `client` is your Discord.js `Client`:

```js
// The channel that you want to send the messages to
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel id')

client.on('message',message => {
  // Ignore bots
  if (message.author.bot) return
  // Send the embed
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
  channel.send({embeds: [embed]}).catch(console.error)
  // Discord.js v12:
  // channel.send(embed).catch(console.error)
})
```

Note that the above code will send the embed for *every* message not sent by a bot, so you will probably want to modify it so that it only sends it when you want it to.

I recommend reading [Discord.js' guide on embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926025733/https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)) or the documentation linked above for more information on how to use embeds.

Comment: I did this and it works perfectry with messages but when I try to add an image with this code ".setImage(message.attachments)" it doesnt work. Am I doing something wrong? I also tried .setImage(message.attachments.first) so now I dont get an error but the Image is in a different message (not embed)

Comment: @EvaHatz [`first`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) is a method and `setImage` accepts a URL, so you’ll need to do `.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need i think is :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("message", async message =>{

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.id === 'channelID'){
        message.delete();
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`${message.content}`)
        .setColor('#d32256')
        .setImage(message.attachments.first().proxyURL)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Instagram', 'ImageOfInsta');
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    },
    });
```

where channelID means : The channel that you want the bot to repost it and ImageOfInsta : an image of instagram logo ! I usually download image or logo first and then re-upload it in Discord.Then i use the link of Discord Image in my codes.

P.S This code works only if you upload an image with a text message!

Answer (score 0):

Here this link leads you to an online embed tool that automatically creates Discord embeds according to your wishes and ideas. this could certainly help you.

Just try this:
-> https://autocode.com/tools/discord/embed-builder/

Comment: The link is not working. Moreover it is recommended to include a description in your answear of what the linked to text is explaining. Can you improve your answer?